# Date parsing in Java using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, simpledateformat

I want to parse a date in this format: "Wed Aug 26 2020 11:26:46 GMT+0200" into a date. But I don't know how to do it. I tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = parser.parse(split[0]); //error line
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

I am getting this error: Unparseable date: "Wed Aug 26 2020 11:26:46 GMT+0200". Is my date format wrong? And if so could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you working on a System whose locale language setting isn't English? Because if you don't provide your SimpleDateFormat a locale it will get and use your Systems default locale, which might not be English and therefor unable to parse the English weekday names. Try to use `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ROOT);` or `Locale.ENGLISH` and see if the error persists

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you **stop** using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Switch to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (`java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time string
        String dateTimeStr = "Wed Aug 26 2020 11:26:46 GMT+0200";

        // Parse the given date-time string to OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s zX", Locale.ENGLISH));

        // Display OffsetDateTime
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-26T11:26:46+02:00
```

## Using the legacy API:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Given date-time string
        String dateTimeStr = "Wed Aug 26 2020 11:26:46 GMT+0200";

        // Define the formatter
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Parse the given date-time string to java.util.Date
        Date date = parser.parse(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed Aug 26 10:26:46 BST 2020
```